# Swift :- Thread 1: Fatal error: Remainder of or division by zero

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, option-type

I am creating a simple calculator with includes Division method (/). I have error handling for nil value or alphabetic words. is there any possible way to guard the crash?

Thread 1: Fatal error: Remainder of or division by zero

```
@objc func divFunc() {

    let a = Int(firstTxtField.text!)
    let b = Int(secondTxtField.text!)


    if (a != nil) && (b != nil)
    {

        resultLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        resultLabel.text = String(a! / b!)
    }
    else
    {
        resultLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
        resultLabel.text = "Invalid No."
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use all of that force unwrapping - It is just asking for a crash.

Check for 0 before performing the division.

```
@objc func divFunc() {
    if let a = Int(firstTxtField.text ?? ""), 
       let b = Int(secondTxtField.text ?? ""), 
       b != 0 {   
        resultLabel.textColor = .white
        resultLabel.text = String(a / b)
    }
    else
    {
        resultLabel.textColor = .red
        resultLabel.text = "Invalid No."
    }
}
```

Comment: I live by the rule: No `@IBOutlet` means No `!` :-)

Comment: this worked perfectly fine. the answer is too simple; great help @paulw11

Comment: @NicolasMiari : sure. I will keep this noted !

Comment: @NicolasMiari you can force unwrap textFields and textViews FYI.

Comment: I will also force downcast cell dequeues since that will fail during development and I want to know about it

Comment: @Paulw11 I prefer to use a `guard let as? else` and a `fatalError()` with a message in those cases, but yeah, the result is the same.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Like I said, `@IBOutlet`.

Comment: @NicolasMiari _whoops_ i meant `text` inside text fields and text views.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Yes, I know those are optional only in paper... still, I use ?? “”